# a Facebook "like" or Twitter "follow" system - in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-like, twitter-follow

Can anyone point me in the right direction to learn about how I could implement a system similar to facebook's "like" or Twitter's "Follow/Unfollow" system that I could create in Rails?

From what I understand I would need to use Unobtrusive Javascript.

I have a Thing model(has_many :likes) and a Like model (belongs_to :thing)

Any pointers?

Comment: if you are starting with RoR, you could take a look at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book (i bought the video casts). this one is excellent. he is doing a sample project where is creating a twitter like website, so it's really close to your needs.

Comment: "Liking" and "Following" are two very different problems.

Comment: basically i want that a user can say that he/she likes/uses a thing. So I have created a model for a "like". I want that when the user clicks the "like/use" button that (depending if one already exists) a new "like" object is created, then the "like" button is changed to a status of "unlike/un-use" - so that the opposite can then be done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do ajax call to a function and implement whatever functionality you like inside that function , (in this case "follow" ), you can do it with :

```
[link_to_function][1]
```

Incase , you are using rails 3.2.4 and it deprecated, you can use(This is from jeremy's comment.
https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/pull/5922#issuecomment-5770442 ):

```
module LinkToFunctionHelper
  def link_to_function(name, *args, &block)
     html_options = args.extract_options!.symbolize_keys

     function = block_given? ? update_page(&block) : args[0] || ''
     onclick = "#{"#{html_options[:onclick]}; " if html_options[:onclick]}#{function}; return false;"
     href = html_options[:href] || '#'

     content_tag(:a, name, html_options.merge(:href => href, :onclick => onclick))
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your comments guys. Will check it all out and report back. Thanks! @d34th4ck3r - where can I read up on implementing that module? Is that something I'd put in my "Things" helper? Cheers

Comment: You can go through this tutorial to learn how to implement complete "follow" functionality: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top. However, if you are interested in just ajax part you can directly read: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec:a_working_follow_button_with_ajax